# xDebug + DBGpProxy in a docker webserver stack

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, proxy, xdebug

I'm trying to setup [DBGpProxy](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpProxy) in a docker container within my dev-webserver stack for multiuser debugging.
The Problem is, that I can't get the proxy connect to the container where xdebug is running.

**First my config, then the problem**

Here is my *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  webserver:
    container_name: apache_webserver
    build: builds/apache
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
      - ./logs:/var/log/
      - ./builds/apache/php-ini-overrides.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-ini-overrides.ini
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
      - 9003:9003
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webserver.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.webserver.rule=Host(`dev.mydomain.local`)"
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
      - default

  dbgpproxy:
    container_name: apache_dbgpproxy
    build: builds/dbgpproxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9100:9100
    networks:
      - traefik_proxy
      - default

  database:
    container_name: apache_mariadb
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    environment: 
      - MYSQL_USER=user_sql
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=some_pwd
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_root_pwd

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
    name: traefik_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

and here is the *Dockerfile* for the proxy:

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install wget

RUN wget -O /var/dbgpProxy https://xdebug.org/files/binaries/dbgpProxy
RUN chmod 0777 /var/dbgpProxy
RUN chmod +x /var/dbgpProxy

CMD /var/dbgpProxy -i 0.0.0.0:9100 -s 127.0.0.1:9003
```

the *php.ini* has these settings:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
```

Docker is running on a (virtualBox) Ubuntu 20.04 Server.Xdebug DBGp proxy Version is 0.3, xDebug is 3.1.0. Docker version 20.10.9, docker-compose version 1.29.2

---

I have no problem, when I got the dbgpProxy running directly on the Ubuntu (IP: 192.168.0.13).

*PHP.ini config:*
xdebug.client_host=**192.168.0.13**

*dbgpProxy call:*
sudo ./dbgpProxy -i **192.168.0.13:9100** -s **192.168.0.13:9003**

*docker-compose.yml:*
same as bevor, but port 9003 isn't published and without the dbgpproxy service (of course :-)

With this config I can debug smoothly.

---

**Now to the Problem:**
As soon As I try to get the dbgpproxy running within the stack I can register my IDE with it, but it does not receive any data from the webserver container.
It seems like my main problem is, that I can't find a way how to connect from one container to another.

I can only bind ports to the dbgpProxy if I use one of these IPs:
localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 (and if I remember right, the apache_dbgpproxy container's IP). In all other (usefull) cases, like when I try to bind the port on the apache_webserver internal IP, I get errors like this:

```
panic: listen tcp 192.168.48.3:9003: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

things like *host.docker.internal* are resolved to the correct (internal) IP of the container, but I'm not allowed to bind them. Same goes for the Ubuntu's IP. I can ping any IP in the networks. Even docker hostnames like *apache_webserver* are resolved fine.

Due to any [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/multiuser-debugging-via-xdebug-proxies.html#configure-multiuser-debugging-via-an-xdebug-proxy-dbgp-server) I found all you need is a computer which can access the xdebug's clients and the server, which I can (at least ping them), s I dont see the problem, why I can't bind anything elsem, but the container itself. Beside: even the ubuntu can only bind itself, but there it is at least no problem.

But how do I get the dbgpproxy container talking with the webserver container?

Comment: `ports:      - 9003:9003` -- what this is for? What are you trying to do here? Who (what service) will be connecting from outside into the container here? Just in case if you have missed it: it's Xdebug that connect to debug client and NOT other way around. In case of DBGpProxy: the IDE connects to Proxy and Xdebug connects to proxy. So why forwarding 9003 port here in that container?

Comment: at first: I'm quite sure I understood who is connecting to whom and how communication between IDE, Proxy and xdebug works. I get it easily running without using docker. the **ports:      - 9003:9003** part is one of many tries to get the address bound, which doesnt work :-( In the end it doesnt matter whether I publish ports, expose ports or do neither, I can't get the proxy to listen to any connection coming from xdebug (if I use the proxy inside a container).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your PHPStorm already listens to port 9003. Try to use a different port.

Comment: Problem is this part: dbgpProxy -i 0.0.0.0:9100 -s 127.0.0.1:9003 No matter what IP (other than the containers own) or Port I put into the command I get an error, that I can't bind the address...